# Android RelativeLayout Design issues

Tags: android, android-layout

I designed one layout which have total 4 RelativeLayout  one is outer cover and 3 are child of it. When I put White color in the outer layout than no spaces are left but when I put 9patch image as drawable image than little default padding/margin are left. Is there any properly which solve the padding/margin issue? I have tried margin negative but it will hide bit layout I think it is not proper solution, here is my layout

[image]

when I put white color as background than my layout look like

Here is the following code of my layout

[image]

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/DetailSection1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/HeaderLayout"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/DetailSection2" 
        
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblRestaurantName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/DetailSection1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/heding_font"
            android:textSize="@dimen/headingFont"
            android:text="Restaurant Name" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgpin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lblRestaurantName"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/pin" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblAddress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lblRestaurantName"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgpin"
            android:text="Address"
            android:textColor="@color/restaurant_list_font"
            android:textSize="@dimen/lableNormalFont"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgphone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lblAddress"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/phn" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblMobile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lblAddress"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgphone"
            android:text="Mobile"
            android:textColor="@color/restaurant_list_font"
            android:textSize="@dimen/lableNormalFont"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgstar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lblMobile"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/star" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblStar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lblMobile"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgstar"
            android:text="Star" 
            android:textColor="@color/restaurant_list_font"
            android:textSize="@dimen/lableNormalFont"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/DetailSection2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/DetailSection1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/DetailSection3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblStar" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgmore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/read_more" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/DetailSection3"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/HeaderLayout"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/photo_cover" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgRestaurant"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lblMobile"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/rihanna" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you please post the 9-patch drawable you are using

Comment: did you try giving the root RelativeLayout width=fillparent and same for the height.

Comment: Thanks!Archie.bpgc i have edited my question with 9 patch image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the 9-patch drawable image you posted:

The **bottom line** which indicates the horizontal data population on the view wasn't drawn from the starting point of left.

I am not sure about it. And I know I wasn't clear in explaining the above line.

Just check this:

Consider the below 9-patch is used as a background for a TextView. If you put some text in it, it will start from the area where the bottom line is drawn. Which mean it will start from the left and go all the way to right.

[image]

If you use the following 9-patch as a background and try the same thing which you did above. Will result in Text not written from the left. It leaves a bit padding.

[image]

That is the reason why you get such result. Of course I am 100% sure about it.

So, just to find out if this works. Try changing the bottom line to fill complete image.

Comment: Thanks! Archie.bpgc. sorry for late reply! your description is right. I have just change my 9 patch image and my problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

I think you better apply the background color for which layout you want exactly.And one more keep the code so that we can understand easily what is your issue.

Comment: thanks Danny! for answer. I want 9 patch image just because it have one drop shadow effect.